# Помогите составить правильное regexp выражение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно из строки с числами и арифметическими знаками извлечь в массив все целые числа, все числа с плавающей точкой и все отрицательные числа (например, если есть в строке "100/0.1+9*-1", то нужно чтобы в результате было ['100', '0.1', '9', '-1']) с помощью regexp.

Для целых и дробных чисел мой код работает, проблема в том, что у меня не получается написать выражение для отрицательных чисел:

```
var digits = calc.result.join('').match(/(\d+\.\d+)|(\d+)|(\*|\/|\+|\-)(?=-\d+)/g);
```

Comment: если остальное работает, добавьте `\-?` в начале

Comment: добавил: /\-?(\d+\.\d+)|\-?(\d+)/g Но теперь получается из строки, например: "2-3" результат: ['2', '-3'], хотя 3 должно быть положительным.

Comment: а так - `(?<!\d)\-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

Comment: @splash58 в js нет `?<!`

Comment: точно, все время забываю :(

Comment: @splash58, хотя в хроме сработало :-) странно

Comment: ругается на знак вопроса var digits = calc.result.join('').match((?<!\d)\-?\d+(?:\.\d+));  -  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?

Comment: @Grundy это от реализации , видимо. В regex101 для js тоже работает

Comment: @C01, это все потому, что ты неверно его вставил - посмотри разницу с вызовом в твоем же вопросе

Comment: @C01 https://regex101.com/r/WWPxyk/1 - вот инструмент

Comment: @splash58, это пока [только в хроме](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) но возможно и остальные подтянутся

Comment: В хроме все работает, но мне нужно решение не только для хрома. Поможете? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @C01, кстати, формально, `2-3` - это то же самое что и `2+(-3)` и разделение на `[2,-3]` вполне допустимо

Comment: Мне не совсем понятно как так написать, чтобы каждый из символов \*\/\+\- могли следовать перед \-\d, я пишу \*|\/|\+|\-(?=-\d), но у меня таким образом символы операций тоже захватываются и минус так и не добавляется к числу

Comment: Или вот, например, (?:\*)-\d/g - в строке "9*-9" запоминает *-9, хотя я указал * в незапоминающих скобках (?:\*) Как сделать так, чтобы * не запоминалась?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const regex = /(?:[*/](-[\d.]+))|([\d\.]+)/g;
const str = `2-1+7*-777/-0.001+0.99`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {

if(m[1]!=null)
  console.log(m[1]);
else if(m[2]!=null)
  console.log(m[2]);

}


//["2", "1", "7", "-777", "-0.001", "0.99"].
```